# File Exists returning false even when I've just created the file

Tags: java, android, file-handling

I am new to android but am having issues with file.exists() returning false right after creating a file.

So I have a button and when pressed this happens :

```
    private void createsavedlistsfile() {
    File file = new File("savedfiles.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
        String filename = "savedfiles.txt";
        String data = "";
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I first check to see if the file exists, then if it does not I create it with blank data. The issue is that if i press the button again, instead of showing already exists the toast message shows success, meaning that the file was overwritten. I do not want this to occur. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you are reading and writing the file in different locations? I'm not familiar with Android, but that would be my first thought to pursue when debugging. Hope that helps!

Comment: Find the location of `savedfiles.txt`.  Where is it being written, if at all?

Comment: Thanks for marking as duplicate! :) the link you pointed me to solved my issue. I wasn't declaring the filepath. I would never have found that other post with that title though.